# How to update Reported properties of Azure IOT device twin using IOT hub rest end point

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

right now i'm using the following code:

```
string patch = "{\"Device\": {\"DeviceState\": \"started\",\"Location\": {\"Latitude\": 50.400188,\"Longitude\": 30.61224}}}";
await _deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwinCollection>(patch));
```

This works fine, my requirement is i want to update the same (reported properties) using IOT hub rest API,  I read something like the following:

> https://{{hubName}}.azure-devices.net/twins/{{deviceId}}?api-version=2016-11-14

A patch request to the above api with a json payload, it is returning **200Ok**, but not updating the twin.

Comment: this is a service-facing endpoint, so it can be used only for changes on the tags and desired properties of the device twin. The device twin reported properties can be changed only from the device-facing endpoint.

Comment: can you please tell me which end point i need to use, i'm not much familiar with this.

Comment: the device twin on the device-facing side is supported only for connection oriented protocols such as AMQP and MQTT in the present time. In other words, there is no REST API endpoint on the device-facing side for device twin properties.

Comment: in the case of avoiding SDK library, I do recommend to use the MQTT protocol directly, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly